# VBA, Code runs fine in excel 2010, slow and not responding error in 2013

Tags: vba, excel

Previously when running my code in 2010 excel version (Version 14.0.7165.5000), it runs in 4 minutes. (however if I run it a second time, it doesnt work)
When switching to 2013 I get 'excel not responding' or it just excel hangs. 
The code opens a files from a directory, loads them into my excel sheet and compiles and transforms some data.

I  stepped through the code, seems to get past this part and now excel isnt responding on my given sub sub , specifically at this part,

```
   'write
    For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Min(nRows, UBound(arr, 1))
        For j = 1 To nCols
            If fromTop Then writeVal = arr(i, j) Else writeVal = arr(UBound(arr, 1) - i + 1, j)
            thisWS.Cells(startRow + i - 1, startCol + j - 1).value = writeVal
        Next j
    Next i
```

Does anyone know why this is? Is there some function I am using that works in 2010 but not in 2013?

Comment: You can break up the code(breakpoints/whatever) and see where the problem is. Also can you optimize the writeArrToWS sub to call ClearContents on the whole workshet range, and also write array to worksheet in one hit

Comment: @MacroMarc , usually its at this line when the excel sheet stops responding, `thisCurveDataRow = findInArrCol(curveNameToMarketData(thisCurveMapRow, 2), 2, curveData)`

Comment: What do you mean by "stop"? Does it crash, return an error or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I get excel not responding, I just stepped through it now, its getting this error when I get to the `writeArrtoWS` sub

Comment: Hard to know based on the size/complexity of the code, as well as Excel-not-responding being hard to track down. The first two things I'd try would be: 1) change the block at the end of generateIRandCRshocks to a "With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IR_CR_Shocks")" block, and 2), change the "clear" portion of writeArrToWS to instead of looping through an array, generate a range object and use the .ClearContents method on it.

Comment: @ChipR. , could you help with the 2) , I am no sure what you mean

Comment: If you have no clue where issue arises, insert `debug.print now, "some comment"` every 10 lines, and make sure you can see the debug window (ctrl+G) while the code runs

Comment: Try to get rid of these loops. Ranges can be read and written AT ONCE, without loops, and that will divide your runtime by 1000 probably. See here for inspiration: http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arrays_en.html

Comment: @patrick-honorez. Yes, that would be my next suggestion: build the array at the end of writeArrToWS and then set the range's value property equal to it. As Patrick said, using arrays to move large amounts of data to and from the excel sheet instead of doing it cell by cell MASSIVELY reduces run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't really an answer. But, I'm not sure the code will format in the comments section. If anyone would care to inform me how to handle this situation in the future, let me know!

Anyway, excel guy, I mean this:

```
'clear
startCell.Resize(nRows, nCols).ClearContents
```

instead of:

```
'clear
For i = 1 To nRows
    For j = 1 To nCols
        thisWS.Cells(startRow + i - 1, startCol + j - 1).value = ""
    Next j
Next i
```

OK... next would be to change the writeArrToWS sub to use an array to write to the whole range at once. I rewrote the sub, incorporating a modified change from my answer above. I think you'd want:

```
Public Sub writeArrToWS(arr() As Variant, startCell As Range, fromTop As Boolean, nRows As Long, nCols As Long)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, startRow As Long, startCol As Long
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet, totalRange As Range

    Set thisWS = startCell.Worksheet

    'set the write range
    Set totalRange = startCell.Resize(nRows, nCols)

    'clear
    totalRange.ClearContents

    'write
    If fromTop Then
        totalRange.Value2 = arr
    Else
        Dim reversedArr() As Variant, swappedRow As Long
        ReDim reversedArr(1 To nRows, 1 To nCols)
        For i = 1 To nRows
            swappedRow = nRows - i + 1
            For j = 1 To nCols
                reversedArr(swappedRow, j) = arr(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
        totalRange.Value2 = reversedArr
    End If

End Sub
```

A few things:

- It seems like if fromTop is true, you just paste the array to the range... did I misunderstand that? If so, it's almost like you just want a "reverseArray" function/subroutine...
- We're basically just generating a new array, "reversedArr", which reverses the order of the rows but leaves the columns alone
- Is there any particular reason why you're passing nRows and nCols to the function? Do you ever want to use the function when nRows and nCols is not just the number of rows and columns of the passed array? If no, then I don't think there's a reason to pass those variables, and instead just generate them inside the function from the passed array.

Comment: Clear worked well actually, just the next `write` part is causing excel not to respond.

Comment: @excelguy. How big are nRows and nCols?

Comment: Rows are roughly 10k , and about 18 cols (do you need exact). Anyway you could help with the arrays?

Comment: Nrows = 7440 , ncols = 18